# Twilio - <Gather> multiple voice replies and transcribing text on outbound call

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api

**OBJECTIVE using the Twilio Framework:**

- place an outbound call
- present 3 questions and record 3 voice response
- transcribe text from the call from the 3 voice responses
- use the # key to signal answer to each question and to move forward

**CURRENTLY WORKING:**

- Python Code calling daisy-chained TwiML hosted via TWiML Bins
- 3 questions being asked
- the call is recorded and can be listened to via Twilio console

**PROBLEMS/WHAT IS NOT WORKING:**

1. there is no transcribed text from the call.
2. there is noticeable time delay in calling the TwiML via the TwiML bin.
3. the #key does not progress to the next question

Any suggestions appreciated:

```
from twilio.rest import Client
account_sid = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
auth_token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

call = client.calls.create(
                        url='http://www.companyname.com/Auditor/MessageName.xml',
                        to="+61437231327",
                        from_='+61437231327',
                        record=True
                    )
print(call.sid)
print(call.status)
#print(call.transcription_text)
print(call.uri)


-------- TWIML hosted website MessageName.xml ---------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Say voice="alice">Collecting Name </Say>
    <Gather input="speech" timeout="3" numDigits="1" action="https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/someTwilBinURLID">
        <Say>Please say Name. Press # when complete</Say>
    </Gather>
  </Response>


-------- TwimlBin TWIML - 2nd required voice response ---------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather input="speech" finishOnKey="#" timeout="3" numDigits="1" action="https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/someTwilBinURLIDForNextVoice">
        <Say>Please say how old you are. Press # when complete</Say>
    </Gather>    
</Response>
-------- TwimlBin TWIML -3rd required voice response ---------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather input="speech" finishOnKey="#" timeout="3" numDigits="1">
        <Say>Please say what your location is. Press # when complete</Say>
    </Gather>    
</Response>
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Nice progress here, but you are going to have to change a few bits around to reach your goal.

First up, [`finishOnKey`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#finishonkey) and [`numDigits`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#numdigits) are only appropriate attributes when [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather) is being used for DTMF input. For speech input, Twilio will listen to the user speaking and when they stop for the [`timeout`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#timeout) (or [`speechTimeout`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#speechtimeout)) length of time, will submit the result. So, for speech input, you can't have the user press `#` when complete, but the conversation should just flow through timeouts.

Next, the transcriptions are sent via the request to the [`<Gather>`'s `action` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#action). To capture that transcribed text you need to set the action to a server you control so that you can read the text.

You could achieve this with a [Twilio Function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/runtime/functions) if you didn't want to stand up your own application. The following code would read and log the result and then return the next TwiML in the call:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  console.log(event.SpeechResult); // SpeechResult is the transcribed text 
  const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  twiml.gather({ input: 'speech', timeout: 3 }).say('The next question');
  callback(null, twiml);
})
```

You would likely want to save the transcribed text to a database of your own as part of this.

I note you're writing the application in Python. You could do this on a Python server of your own as well.

Finally, I'm not sure what would be causing a delay with your TwiML Bins. It might be worth playing about with the `timeout` value to optimise that.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: how to access the console.log?

Comment: @X10D when you call `console.log` the result is written out to the log. In Twilio Functions, log events are written below the Function within the Twilio console.

Comment: @philnash do you know if you can do both a gather of voice and dtmf?  I ask because it is odd to offer a list as a variable but only offer one or the other.  And specifically, how many times have you had the option to do either with the bank.  Say a response or use the keypad - it is offered by most banks now.  Twilio seems geared to offer this.

Comment: You absolutely can @DaveFriedel. Just choose `<Gather input="speech dtmf">`.

Comment: Then question @philnash - how is the return function cause I don't see it in docs for both. e.g. for speech results from gather public TwiMLResult OnComplete(string SpeechResult, double Confidence) { } - Can I assume the request.Digits is filled in? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @DaveFriedel the return comes as a webhook to the `action` URL you add to the `<Gather>` element. If you include both speech and dtmf then you will need to check whether the `Digits` or the `SpeechResult` parameter has data. Check out the details here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#action